# Bidirectional Send/Ack Android Beam

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

i'm using 2 Galaxy S3 and i send a message from one to the other. I want the other to send back a response like "received msg" 
   i'm using the android beam demo, and i want to add this ack.I send the ack message when i treat the first message in ProcessIntent with a simple "sendNdefMessage"? how do i manage the receipt of the ack in the other device?

```
void processIntent(Intent intent) {
    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
            NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // only one message sent during the beam
    NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
    // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
    mInfoText.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));

    //ack message
    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(ackMsg, this);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a message back, unfortunately. However, the device that sent the message knows when it has been received successfully. Your app can be notified of this by registering a callback with [`NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback%28android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29)

Comment: it means you cannot establish a communication between 2 devices. You only can send 1 message at a time.
How can you do otherwise?

Comment: This is all the NFC peer-to-peer functionality that has currently been implemented Android... :(